# Using react-code-blocks library .Yarn dev runs fine but during yard build i get Type error

Tags: reactjs, npm

Trying to run [https://github.com/hauptrolle/chakra-templates]on local machine .yarn dev command runs fine and project runs without any issue.When i try to run yarn build i get Type error for

```
  61 |       <CodeBlock
> 62 |         text={code}
     |         ^
  63 |         language={'tsx'}
  64 |         theme={a11yDark}
  65 |         startingLineNumber={0}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

This project is using react-code-blocks for formatting code but text property not being recognized here but in official website it is the property.Being clueless whats wrong here.
Attaching screenshot of code snippet for better understanding

[image]

Tried upgrading npm and node but its not working also google but didn't get any solution